# How to set multiple values into a client side people picker

Tags: sharepoint

i have a list with a people picker column which takes multiple inputs.I have a form created using content editor web part in which i have a client side people picker how to set multiple values into a client side people picker using jsom

Answer (score 0):

Normally you define client people control in HTML:

```
<div id="control" title="Users" spclientpeoplepicker="true"></div>
```

Then you need to initialize it.

To initialize it properly you need to assure that these javascripts files are loaded: `autofill.js`,  `clienttemplates.js`, `clientforms.js`, `clientpeoplepicker.js`

**JavaScript set control value code:**

Entities are validate automatically with function `AddUserKeys`

```
var userField = $("input[id$='ClientPeoplePicker_EditorInput']").get(0); // simplified user control search, real word scenario, first search proper row in your form
var peoplepicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.PickerObjectFromSubElement(userField);
peoplepicker.AddUserKeys("Login1"); // or display name
peoplepicker.AddUserKeys("Login2");
```

**JavaScript init control code:**

```
SP.SOD.loadMultiple(['autofill.js', 'clienttemplates.js', 'clientforms.js', 'clientpeoplepicker.js'], registerControls);

function registerControls() {
    initPeoplePicker('control');
}

function initPeoplePicker (id, user) {
    // Create a schema to store picker properties, and set the properties.
    var schema = {};
    schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User'; //,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
    schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
    schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;
    schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = true;
    schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
    schema['Width'] = '311px';

    // use code below to init controls with selected user   
    /*
    var users = new Array(1);
    var defaultUser = {};
    defaultUser.AutoFillDisplayText = user.Value;
    defaultUser.AutoFillKey = user.get_loginName();
    defaultUser.Description = user.get_email();
    defaultUser.DisplayText = user.get_title();
    defaultUser.EntityType = "User";
    defaultUser.IsResolved = true;
    defaultUser.Key = user.get_loginName();
    defaultUser.Resolved = true;
    users[0] = defaultUser;
    */

    // Render and initialize the picker.
    // Pass the ID of the DOM element that contains the picker, an array of initial
    // PickerEntity objects to set the picker value, and a schema that defines
    // picker properties.
    SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(id, null/*users*/, schema);
}
```

Comment: i don't want to get users from a people picker i want to set values to a people picker from a list

Comment: Hi hari babu, did you find the solution for this issue please?

Comment: do you see the code under the comment: use code below to init controls with selected user?